Unable to view the OK and CANCEL buttons at the bottom of this Insert Table/Form Screen in Oracle BI Publisher Desktop
Unable to view the OK and CANCEL buttons at the bottom of this Insert Table/Form Screen in Oracle BI Publisher Desktop.
Also some other options are not showing such as Formula option in the running totals
Screenshot of the Insert Table/Form Screen 
